# HTTPS and SecurePages Infinite Redirect - How do I reset which pages are always HTTPS?

Tags: redirection, security

Using [Secure Pages](https://drupal.org/project/securepages), I checked the option to have the site always be using HTTPS when logged in as an administrator, but now I have an infinite redirection issue, and I cannot log-in and navigate the site, leaving me to edit the settings manually.

How do I "uncheck", or revert the option that I selected manually in SecurePages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pulled this directly from the README.txt of the module.

> ### Configuration
>
> Generally on test/development servers you do not have access to SSL,
>   so  generally you would like to disable secure pages on these systems.
>
> To do this add the following to your settings.php
>
> $conf['securepages_enable'] = 0;
>
> ### Removal of SecurePages
>
> In the case where your SSL mode has been disabled and you can no
>   longer access the administration section of your site to disable
>   securepages you can do one of the 2 following things.
>
> 1. Use the above method to disable securepages.
> 2. delete the secure pages module from your site.
>
> If you can use the first option but if you can't edit your
>   settings.php then deleting it will not break your site, but will leave
>   some variables that are set by secure pages.

Comment: Hmm.  Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.  Do you have any more ideas?  I really appreciate the help, by the way.

Would I have to modify `securepages_roles`?

Comment: try securepages_switch instead, updated my post. One of those variable controls whether your site uses secure pages or not.

Comment: new answer for you...

Comment: Haha!  That did it, thank you, sir.  I totally looked right over the readme.  Gotta remind myself to RTFM.